# Send xml data as multipart/form-data using WebRequest c#

Tags: c#, xml, multipartform-data, webrequest

I am posting to an API that seems to insist on receiving XML data as multipart/form-data.
The request works in SOAP UI. But, fails in c#. Below is the code submitted based on https://technet.rapaport.com/Info/LotUpload/SampleCode/Full_Example.aspx

```
string url = string.Format("url");

string strTkn = "strTkn";

string hdrXml = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n<importdata>\n --redacted-XML-- \n</importdata>");


WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + strTkn);

string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

string formContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
request.ContentType = formContentType;
request.Method = "POST";
Stream postDataStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();


string fileHeaderTemplate = Environment.NewLine + "--" + boundary + Environment.NewLine +
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"xml\"; filename=\"request\"" +
Environment.NewLine + "Content-Type: text/xml" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

byte[] byteHdr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileHeaderTemplate);

byte[] byteEnd = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("--" + boundary + "--");

byte[] byteArray = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hdrXml);

postDataStream.Write(byteHdr, 0, byteHdr.Length);

postDataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

postDataStream.Write(byteEnd, 0, byteEnd.Length);

postDataStream.Position = 0;

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

int bytesRead = 0;

request.ContentLength = postDataStream.Length;

Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();

while ((bytesRead = postDataStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
{
reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}

postDataStream.Close();

reqStream.Close();

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

string Result = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

A MIME attachment starts with two dashes at the beginning of a new line.    See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)

You have an extra line starting with two dashes

Here is your MIME attachment

1. byteHdr :

------------------------------8d90d21ca8659b4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xml"; filename="request"
Content-Type: text/xml

2. byteEnd

------------------------------8d90d21ca8659b4--

3. byteArray : Below the two dashes do not start at beginning of new line.

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <importdata>
     --redacted-XML-- 
    </importdata>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. The API team logs show the error with the header in their logs. And, we are yet to figure out the issue. Below is the error from error logs.                                                                                                
              System.FormatException: The header contains invalid values at index 0: 'multipart/form-data; boundary=------=_Part_0_32251531.1619905346710'
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderParser`1.ParseValue(StringSegment value, Int32& index)

Comment: The xml information is edited in the example and does not show the complete xml data. So, the two dashes in the XML was not part of the original request.

Comment: There has to be a return after the line with dashes.  Look at link above for the correct syntax of message.  The http header cannot contain dashes.  A HTTP message has three parts 1) The http header 2) The body (optional) 3) Attachments.(optional)  The dashes are after the body.  Your error indicates the dashes are in the header.